# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Buffer' (Next Auth & TS)

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth, credential-providers

I'm encountering the following TypeScript error:

**"Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Buffer'."**

I'm integrating NextAuth with my Next.js 14 application and configuring login credentials to compare passwords during login. However, I'm facing this error specifically with the input password in the following line:

```
  const passwordOk =
          existingUser && bcrypt.compareSync(password, existingUser.password)
```

and this is the full options file

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import connectMongoDB from "@/lib/mongodb"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import User from "@/models/user"

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        // email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "email" },
        // password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const email = credentials?.email
        const password = credentials?.password
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        await connectMongoDB()
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email })
        const passwordOk =
          existingUser && bcrypt.compareSync(password, existingUser.password)

        if (passwordOk) {
          // Any object returned will be saved in `ser` property of the JWT
          return existingUser
        } else {
          // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
          return null

          // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

I have tried to assign this type manually on the password but didn't work

```
        const password: string | Buffer = credentials?.password
```

I also tried this

```
const passwordOk =
          existingUser &&
          password &&
          bcrypt.compareSync(password, existingUser.password)
```

and the error disappeared, but I'm not sure if it is a best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`credentials?.password` might return `undefined` because of Optional chaining `?.` and `compareSync` couldn't be evaluated with an `undefined` as a first parameter, hence, you are seeing this error.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining (?.) operator accesses an object's property or
> calls a function. If the object accessed or function called using this
> operator is `undefined` or `null`, the expression short circuits and
> evaluates to `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

Since `passwordOk` will be affected by `password` value, it's recommended to check for its value (and for the email as well) before continuing with the excution, though, a [Guard Clause](https://medium.com/@timothydan/javascript-guard-clauses-64b999e3240) would be great here:

```
const email = credentials?.email;
const password = credentials?.password;
if (!email || !password) return;
// rest of the code
```

This should remove the error.

Another solution that **I don't really recommend in such cases** (due to somehow breaking the typescript checking system) is to use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) and the syntax is pretty easy, simply postfix your password with exclamation mark, i.e. `credentials.password!` this tells typescript that you are pretty sure that this expression will return a value and will never be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer to my question. Your explanation was incredibly helpful, and I really appreciate the effort you put into helping me solve my issue. Have a great day!